# How do I clean these gloves so they do not leave marks?

Tags: cleaning

They leave marks on dishes in the pattern of the gloves.

#### Details

- Tried soap, bleach, ammonia, vinegar, scalding water, microfiber cloth.
- Only the fingertips leave marks and are sticky.
- Palms or back of fingers with the same pattern are not sticky, nor are flat parts.
- Brand: Playtex
- The marks on glass come off with microfiber cloth and pressure.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Is it possible the gloves are clean but your dishes have a smooth veneer of oily residue that is simply agitated by being touched?

Comment: No that's not possible. This particular example was washed several times and rubbed with a microfiber cloth to verify cleanliness. The palms and back of fingers with same pattern do not leave a pattern, nor does bare skin fingertips.

Comment: Wow...I feel totally ahead of the curve if nothing in my refrigerator is actively trying to escape.

Comment: Likely the gloves were poorly vulcanized: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcanization or are simply oxidizing. The cure is to get a new set of gloves, preferably from a source that does a better jub curing its latex.

Comment: This problem can occur after using a solvent while wearing the gloves. The solvent dissolves the affected areas of the glove in contact with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clean rubber gloves can still leave marks. My guess is that the finger pads are more wornout (at microscopic level) and you've reached the not so smooth 'meat' part of the rubber that will stick and rub off on things.

Try with new gloves, or surgical latex gloves, or if marks on glass drive you nuts (like some of us), you can try microfiber gloves over rubber gloves.

Comment: I thought buying brand name for 4x the cost would be better, but I was wrong. I might as well stick with dollar store brand.

Answer (score 3):

The latex rubber gloves break down over time becoming sticky and messy.  Aging is sped up by using in very hot water.  The "fingerprint" marks left on stainless steel pots and clear glass containers can be easily removed by wiping with a paper towel dampened with vegetable oil.  The glove marks are an organic and vegetable oil is an organic solvent.  The oil can then be washed off with warm soapy water.  Once gloves become sticky, they should be discarded.  An alternative is disposable vinyl, latex, or nitrile (surgical) gloves.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if the gloves were greasy before, try using a grease fighting dishwashing detergent.  Rub your hands together with the soap to remove all grease.  Make sure to scrub thoroughly, like you were going into surgery.  Rinse with hot water.  This usually works for me.  Sometimes if your gloves are aging, the rubber will become tacky, if this is the case, replace the gloves.

Answer (score -1):

We have been having the same problem.  I searched online, and found that it is the gloves wearing down. Probably better off using a different brand.  Check out the reviews that led me to this answer: http://www.amazon.com/review/R3HBPYRGEGLSI7/#R3HBPYRGEGLSI7

Comment: It would probably be better to quote the relevant review in your post so people don't have to click the link. Sometimes websites are not accessible or links change. You can use CTRL + Q in the edit window to format highlighted text as a quote.